# "defaults read com.apple.dock" as Objective C method

Tags: objective-c, macos

I try to read the plist / xml file which is behind the terminal commando:

```
defaults read com.apple.dock
```

I tried `NSUserDefaults` without success. Maybe you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: "I tried NSUserDefaults without success." Show us what you tried. Perhaps there was just a small thing that needed to be changed. It's more helpful to see what you have tried (with code) so we can make small suggestions, and don't recommend things you've already tried.

Comment: I don't have a glue. I tried to use NSUserdefaults to look for a domain, but this was wrong.

Comment: Why do you want to access a file created by somebody else?  The defaults CLT has become obsolete in this respect.  What does Apple say about accessing a file that you don't own outside your sandboxed folder?

Comment: Because I want to write a simple (one button) application which sets a default which makes my Mac OSX dock 2d and non-glossy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [JWWalker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19056817/265072) that uses CoreFoundation APIs works fine, a more modern way is to use Foundation APIs, like so:

```
if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.apple.dock") {
  let orientation = defaults.string(forKey: "orientation")
  let autohide = defaults.bool(forKey: "autohide")
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use CFPreferences, for example

```
CFStringRef orient = (CFStringRef) CFPreferencesCopyAppValue( CFSTR("orientation"), CFSTR("com.apple.dock") );
Boolean hidesIsValid = false;
Boolean hides = CFPreferencesGetAppBooleanValue( CFSTR("autohide"), CFSTR("com.apple.dock"), &hidesIsValid );
```